# Get hash value with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a hash like this

```
hash_variable = {"74"=> {"x"=>{"order_id"=>"3643731"}, "x"=>{"order_id"=>"618787", "detail_id"=>"115", "qty"=>"1"}}}
```

Note: `"x" -> 1..n` is from index of each.

I want to reject hash if `detail_id` is `nil`.  I tried with regex:

```
hash_variable.each do |items|
  unless items[/(\d+)/][:detail_id].nil?
    p items
  end
end
# => `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`
```

Can I use regex for "x" to get any hash have `detail_id` key ? if not, how can I reject hash if `detail_id` is nil?

Comment: Your hash is invalid: you can't get two 'x' keys. Keys should be unique

Comment: `"x" -> 1..n` from index of each, they are unique..

Comment: what do you want to get?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @fl00r It is not invalid, it is redundant.

Comment: @sawa : exactly, it's redudant, but I can solve that. Sorry, previously I'm not put the question on my post, so that makes you be a downvoter, not a helper.

Comment: @itx People do get frustrated when your question contains code that doesn't make sense. Having two `x` keys is an example of this. If those are numbers in the actual code, `"1"` and `"2"` would have been better. In any case, your sample data should serve as a demonstration of the actual data you have, and allow people to use it verbatim for showing how their solution works.

Comment: @tadman : thanks for your suggestion, I will be better. Actually I already wrote a note in my post, that "x" is `"1".."n"` where x is an iteration of the index, why I'm not use `"1"` or `"2"` instead `"x"`? because I want some helper understand, `"x"` can contain anything (`"1".."n"`). But maybe I have less good explanation in English, thus making people misunderstand what I want.

Comment: Notes tend to confuse the issue no matter what language they're written in. People here read code first and try and fix it, and if it has errors to start with, it derails the conversation. There's an art to writing a minimal example of your problem, but with practice you get better.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved my problem.

```
hash_variable = {"74"=> {"0"=>{"order_id"=>"3643731"}, "1"=>{"order_id"=>"618787", "detail_id"=>"115", "qty"=>"1"}}}
hash_variable.each do |key,items|
 p items.select { |k,v| !v['detail_id'].nil? }
end
# {"1"=>{"order_id"=>"618787", "detail_id"=>"115", "qty"=>"1"}}
```

Update from tadman's suggestion better than above

```
hash_variable.each do |key,items|
 p items.select { |k,v| v['detail_id'] }
end
```

Comment: `items.select { |k, v| v['detail_id'] }` is much more concise here unless you're expecting `v['detail_id']` to be literally `false` on occasion.